# JBOSS 7 & Batch Service

Tags: jboss7.x

I have a server side built on the top of JBOSS 7 AS.

I have a need to run a batch process every 24 hours to perform some operations on the DB. Whilst it is easy to implement the service, I am wondering what the best is to launch is... Any examples available?

In my old JBOSS days, I would have kicked this off through a boostrap servlet.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an EJB3.1 Timer: http://javahowto.blogspot.be/2010/04/ejb-31-timer-simple-example.html

```
@Stateless
public class BatchLauncher {

   @Schedule(hour = "12", minute = "0")
   private void checkInventory() {
```

By default, JBoss 7 will scan your war/ear for ejb3 annotated classes. 
For @Stateless beans, JBoss will create a singleton and make it accessible via JNDI.

Inside the singletons, JBoss 7 will find the @Schedule annotation and schedule the method invocation using the schedule.